# Is Moisture Resistant plywood good enough for furniture?

Tags: furniture, plywood, television, closet

I'm planning to build furniture for home.

I'm confused whether to use MR (Moisture Resistant) plywood(IS 303 standard) or BWP (Boiling Water Proof) plywood (IS 710 standard) for furniture.

I'm happy to use BWP plywood for kitchen but what about other furniture like cupboard, showcase, TV stand, etc.

Seller advised me to buy BWP for everything as the home is 25km from coast and there will be humidity.

I feel MR should do fine because furniture are no where near the kitchen or bathroom.

Any ideas are welcome

FYI:
BWP is bit expensive than MR
Here is the [link](https://www.zadinteriors.com/blog/the-difference-between-303-710-grade-plywood/) detailing what' BWP , MR and other standards

Please find sketch of my furniture [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/238559/142629)

Comment: You will be painting/staining/sealing the furniture after making or just leaving as bare wood?  Bare wood you might want the better stuff.

Comment: Outside , I'd be lamenating with 0.8mm thickness and inside I'd be doing putty and paint for smoothness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on budget go with **MR plywood** for Kitchen and other humid places ( IS 303 ) and Hardwood ply for less humid places.

But make sure you are using the **quality laminates** and paint the **non-laminated areas** with water or termite resistant paints.

There are some BWP or BWR plywoods that are fire retardant as well , it all comes down to what your budget is.