# Is it ok to use hardwood ply for cupboard and furnitures

Tags: plywood, television, closet

I have been advised by plywood sellers to buy BWP(Boiling water protection) grade plywood from kitchen to cupboard,showcase,TV stand and it's expensive as well.

But some people suggested me to use Moisture resistance grade plywood for cupboard and its cheaper than BWP but again it's expensive though

I personally feel except kitchen for any other furnitures I should just use hardwood ply and that should be enough if there's any possibility of water coming in contact either as liquid form or gas then Hardwood ply should do and it's relatively affordable as well.

FYI:
From my home the coast is 25 km and average temperature is 30 degree Celsius so would it be ok for me to go ahead with Hardwood ply or I should consider Moisture resistance grade ?

Please find [sketch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/238559/142629) of my furnitures here

Please advise

Comment: When you say "hardwood" do you mean solid wood, or something like a furniture grade hardwood plywood?  Also, I've never heard of BWP - sounds interesting but overkill.

Comment: Hardwood plywood

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Moisture Resistant plywood good enough for Furnitures](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/238587/is-moisture-resistant-plywood-good-enough-for-furnitures)

Comment: @SolarMike - That question hasn't got any valid answer and the question is very different as well\

Comment: Plywood sellers might not be the best.  Would try asking people who make furniture locally what they use.  Most of the local types of wood should be separated into indoor and outdoor use.  Imagine BWP is for outdoor use.

Comment: The cabinets in my kitchen were custom made out of some sort of (cheap) grade of plywood long before I moved in 30 years ago. They were painted shortly after I moved in, and are showing no indication of water damage, despite housing the kitchen sink. I wouldn't be too worried about using just "plain" plywood. I live in the US Midwest where temps of 90°F+ (32°C) and humidity in the 80-95% range are common during the summer.

Comment: I worked in a plywood mill for a few years and the only difference between regular plywood and marine grade was the quality of the veneer, they all used the same glue, I have never heard of boiling water resistant

Comment: @FreeMan - Good to know.

Comment: @EdBeal - Ok , the quality is one extra plus though.

Comment: Amogam, yes , I am not saying that is not worth the cost the clear veneers and plugged core is a lot more work to build the plywood. the plant I worked at was a large one and we ran 1 kind of glue on the lay up line. That same glue was pumped over to the hand laid that had the tight tolerances but the difference was how tight the core layers were. Look at the side of cheap ply and you will see holes between layers look at the expensive stuff and their are only cracks between pieces of core. I knew nothing about how it was made in the 70’s and my first kitchen cabinets are still fine last week.

Comment: Interesting , I will keep this in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BWP** is best for any place which has more moisture content such as Kitchen,Restroom, front yard , back yard.

**Normal hardwood** is ok for places like Bedroom. But there's no harm in going for **BWP** or **MR** as well.

There are so many things like warranty , nail bearing capacity , anti termite chemicals that you have to take into account before choosing.

Remember natural wood such as pine, teak are better than engineered woods such as hardwood ply or MR or BWP.

If you are more concerned about dampness in places like outdoor you may have a look at WPC ( Wood Plastic Composite )

Comment: There may be no harm in using BWP or MR plywood in non-wet areas other than additional cost and releasing potentially harmful chemicals when cutting it for no good reason.

Comment: @FreeMan - Like you said , it's better to go with more economical and non-toxic way.